# Debugging a Visual Basic Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a simple VBA macro function that would accept a Colum/ Range of values and if any cell value is greater than 100, it should edit the color of the adjacent cell on the left to gree).

So within my for loop,

```
    Function Test(Rngg As Range) As String
    x = 0
    x2 =0
    For Each Cell in Rngg
    If Cell.Value > 100 Then
    x = x+1
    Cell.Offset(,-1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    Else
    x2 = x2+1
    End if
    Next Cell
    Test = :There are "+x+" large orders and"+ x+ " Short orders"
    Msgbox(Test)
   End Function
```

Could someone please help point out and tell me what is wrong with this piece of code? Note Rngg is a user inputted range.

No Compile errors but when I basically try using the function as a formula on excel I keep getting a Value error

Comment: You may want to include what error you are getting. Also, it's not going to work if `Rngg` includes the first column, since there is no column to the left of that. Also, `,Interior` should not be using a comma... it should be `.Interior`

Comment: i think to use offset you have to select the cell.  I prefer to use: For x = 1 to qnt            If thisworkbook.sheets("yoursheet").cell(x,2).value > 100 then '2 is column B ...Follows the logic.

Comment: @braX Hi I updated the code and there are no compile errors. On trying to use the function, I constantly seem to get a Value error.

Comment: You do not want `x.Offset` - you want `Cell.Offset` - `x` is a number, so it does not have properties and methods.

Comment: @braX I apologize, that was a typo on my part. The code still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You should try some of the codes in your answers instead then. If you have problems with their codes, you can comment on their answers with your questions.

Answer (score 0):

### Color by Value

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ColorByValueTEST()
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("B2:B21")
    ColorByValue rg, 100, -1, vbGreen
End Sub

Sub ColorByValue( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        ByVal GreaterThanValue As Double, _
        ByVal ColumnOffset As Long, _
        ByVal DestinationColor As Long)
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = rg.Columns(1)
    If srg.Column + ColumnOffset < 1 Then Exit Sub
    If srg.Column + ColumnOffset > srg.Worksheet.Columns.Count Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        If IsNumeric(sCell) Then
            If sCell.Value > GreaterThanValue Then
                If drg Is Nothing Then
                    Set drg = sCell.Offset(, ColumnOffset)
                Else
                    Set drg = Union(drg, sCell.Offset(, ColumnOffset))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sCell
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    srg.Offset(, ColumnOffset).Interior.Color = xlNone
    drg.Interior.Color = DestinationColor

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Most of the warnings are clear in the comments, but this procedure probably does what you want. There's a couple things to lookout for with an inputbox.

```
Sub inputBoxMacro()
Dim aRngg As Range, Cell As Range

On Error GoTo endThis 'used in case user cancels
Set aRnggr = Application.InputBox(Title:="The InputBox Title", Prompt:="Grab some cells", _
      Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
    

For Each Cell In Intersect(aRngg, aRngg.Worksheet.UsedRange).Cells
    If Cell.Column = 1 Then
        'skip since nothing to the left
    ElseIf Cell.Value > 50 Then
        Cell.Offset(, -1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    End If
Next Cell


endThis:
End Sub
```